# Jquery Fullcalendar selectHelper function not working

Tags: fullcalendar

According to the fullcalendar docs [selectHelper](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/selectHelper/) accepts a function:

> A function can also be specified for drawing custom elements. It will
>   be given 2 arguments: the selection's start date and end date (Moment
>   objects). It must return a DOM element that will be used.

However this feature doesn't work. In fact nothing in the source code checks selectHelper for typeof function.

Any ideas?

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,basicWeek,agendaDay,basicDay'
        },
        date: '2014-01-12',
        defaultView: 'month',
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: function(start, end) {
            return $("<div style='background:red' />").text(start+' '+end);
        },

        editable: true,
        events: [
            {
                title: 'All Day Event',
                start: '2014-01-01'
            },
            {
                title: 'Long Event',
                start: '2014-01-07',
                end: '2014-01-10'
            },
            {
                id: 999,
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                start: '2014-01-09T16:00:00'
            },
            {
                id: 999,
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                start: '2014-01-16T16:00:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Meeting',
                start: '2014-01-12T10:30:00',
                end: '2014-01-12T12:30:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Lunch',
                start: '2014-01-12T12:00:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Birthday Party',
                start: '2014-01-13T07:00:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Click for Google',
                url: 'http://google.com/',
                start: '2014-01-28'
            }
        ]
    });


});
```

Comment: I can't find anything in the current source as well... Docs must be a bit ahead of themselves :(

Answer (score 1):

That is definitely a bug

I submitted an issue on GitHub

https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar/issues/2832